# Writing in file | Swi-Prolog | Windows

Tags: prolog

Some script is working successful by swi-prolog 5.11.11 on linux-system, but not so well on windows-system by Swi-Prolog 5.6.48

```
main :-
    open('output.txt',write,OS),
    elements(Points),
    get_set(Eq, Points),
    alpha_isotone(Eq, Points),
    write(OS,Eq),nl(OS),
    false,
    close(OS).
```

Problem - under the windows file *output.txt* is empty and all information is staying in pseudo-terminal.
Under linux it's working well, but end of file is missed often. Like

```
>> tail output.txt      
[6,1,3,6,6,6]
[6,1,6,6,6,6]
[6,3,1,6,6,6]
[6,3,3,6,3,6]
[6,3,3,6,5,6]
[6,3,3,6,6,6]
[6,3,6,6,6,6]
[6,6,1,6,6,6]
[6,6,3,6,6,6]
[6,6,6,
```

What am I doing wrong? (except of my english)

Comment: As written the close(OS) cannot be reached; the **main/0** goal fails just before reaching it.  Shouldn't the close(OS) be done in an alternative clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one wanted to keep the close(OS) within a "single" **main/0** clause, this also works:

```
main :-
    open('output.txt',write,OS),
    (   elements(Points),
        get_set(Eq, Points),
        alpha_isotone(Eq, Points),
        write(OS,Eq),nl(OS),
        false
        ;
        close(OS)
    ).
```

This syntax is not recommended as it is hard to remember what is the precedence of the conjunction `,` versus disjunction `;` unless you frequently use such coding, and it is on that account less readable than the version presented by larsmans.

Prolog defines the relative precedence of operators, even for AND, OR, and "neck" `:-`, by assigning **Precedence** values to each (users do this with **op/3** when defining their own operators), ranging from 0 to 1200.

There is also a reversal of  [the usual convention](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/11precedence/) here, in that we normally mean the higher precedence operator is to be applied before lower precedence operators.  But in Prolog  [the lower **Precedence** value](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/pi3/prolog/Manual/operators.html) indicates an operator binds (is applied) first.

Actual precedence values vary with the implementation, but conjunction `,` has lower **Precedence** value than disjunction `;` and thus binds first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this was meant to be a failure-driven loop. It doesn't work because the `close/1` call, as @hardmath says, is never reached since it is preceded by a `fail/1` in the same clause. In effect, the output file is apparently not flushed. This failure-driven loop should be written as:

```
main :-
    open('output.txt', write, OS),
    main(OS).

main(OS) :-
    elements(Points),
    get_set(Eq, Points),
    alpha_isotone(Eq, Points),
    write(OS,Eq), nl(OS),
    false.
main(OS) :- close(OS).
```

Comment: The different effects on the improperly closed files, Linux vs. Windows, are probably due to different buffering strategies.  Apparently on program termination Windows closes the file without ever flushing any write-buffer, thus producing an empty file.  Linux is more robust, but as you've seen the program termination may lose a few characters.

Comment: @hardmath: this may not even be a matter of "robustness", but just of different buffer size between OSs.