# Writing to a file in gprolog

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

How do I write all the solutions obtained from a prolog program to a file?

Comment: Actually, there are some really close question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736384/writing-in-file-swi-prolog-windows

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is to nest the call to your "solutions" predicate inside a repeat/fail loop, at the penultimate step of which the solution is written to a file.

Since the post is short on details of what kind of solution is involved (and thus how difficult the writing of terms might be, e.g. if it is desired to be able to reinstantiate one or more terms from reading the written file back at some point), let's start with a simple illustration, where solutions are just integers.

We have the following nondeterministic predicate:

```
mySolution(X) :- for(X,1,10).
```

Note **for/3** is a built-in predicate for GNU Prolog.  SWI-Prolog has the similar predicate **between/3**, and Amzi! Prolog has **for/4** with an extra argument allowing the increment to be something other than +1.  A user implementation would be:

```
for(Low,Low,High) :- Low =< High.
for(New,Low,High) :-
    Now is Low + 1,
    Now =< High,
    for(New,Now,High).
```

such that the goal `mySolution(X)` will succeed in a predictably finite number of ways.

The file output could be achieved either by using GNU-Prolog's stream faculties, or by doing a command-line redirection of console output.  We'll illustrate the first possibility although the second one may be simpler and more flexible in many cases.

```
main :-
    open('myOutput.txt',write,ID),
    (   ( mySolution(X), write(ID,X), nl(ID), fail )
      ; close(ID)
    ).
```

Like many Prolog implementations, GNU-Prolog offers several stream and non-stream variants on the **write** predicate, and you can find [here the relevant documentation](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc156).  For **open** and **close** look at [this link](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#open/4) and [that link](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#close/2).

**Added:** I threw in a **nl/1** call to separate the solutions in the output file.

Comment: @hardmath: `mySolution(N)` does not terminate, nor does any ground goal with a valid expression as argument. So the file will never be closed.

Comment: @false:  Good catch, I'll fix it!

Comment: @hardmath: `between(1,10,X)`.

Comment: @false:  Thanks again.  I didn't want to try and edit from my phone!

Comment: @hardmath: GNU Prolog has `between/3` too! In fact, it is part of the Prolog prologue!

Comment: @false: Well, I looked for `between/3` in the [online manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html) and didn't find it, and I've now tried it in my GNU Prolog 1.4.1 console:  existence_error(procedure,between/3).  Is it in a library?  BTW I got the arguments out of order and wound up doing a dreaded edit from my phone in the end.  :-(

Comment: @hardmath: `between/3` is present in GNU 1.4.1 since [2012-04-26](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/unstable/?C=M;O=D). The GNU built-in [`for/3`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc193) has the arguments in the wrong order. The counter must be the last argument to facilitate higher-order programming. Think of `maplist(between(1,4),[X,Y,Z])`.